# R: Suppress table grid in addtable2plot{plotrix}

Tags: r

I am using `addtable2plot()` in the `plotrix` package. One peculiar problems is that I can't get rid of the table grid. The `hlines` and `vlines` options do not make any difference. What am I doing wrong?

```
testdf<-data.frame(Before=c(10,7,5),During=c(8,6,2),After=c(5,3,4))
rownames(testdf)<-c("Red","Green","Blue")
barp(testdf,main="Test addtable2plot",ylab="Value",
     names.arg=colnames(testdf),col=2:4)
# show most of the options
addtable2plot(2,8,testdf,bty="n",display.rownames=TRUE, hlines=FALSE, vlines=FALSE,title="The table")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debugging the code, the basic problem is that `rect` is called for each cell ... effectively creating a grid whether or not horizontal and vertical line segments are drawn

I solved this (sort of) as follows:

- `addtable2plotx <- fix(addtable2plot)` (opens an editor)
- add `if (hlines && vlines)` before `rect(...` on line 64 of the file

re-make your plot using `addtable2plotx` instead of `addtable2plot`.  (There still seem to be a few spurious lines there, but the rectangles are gone.)

You might try contacting the package maintainer about this, to determine if this is a bug or if we're mis-reading the intention of the `hlines` and `vlines` arguments in the documentation (in which case a documentation tweak might be in order)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Ben. I'm mailing the package maintainer. If I get a response, I'll post it here.

Comment: Addendum: Jim Lemon (package maintainer) says this is a bug which apparently crept in while adding a feature of self-adjusting table widths. Should be fixed in a month or so.